# Configure pfSense VLAN Trunk

Tags: cisco, vlan, firewall, trunk, pfsense

I have setup a pfSense box as a transparent firewall between my Cisco router and first Cisco switch:

```
CISCO ROUTER - 10.10.1.253
↓
PFSENSE - OPT1 BRIDGE - 10.10.1.252
↓
CISCO CORE SWITCH - 10.10.1.250
```

The port on the router and the switch facing the firewall are both trunk ports as the network has many VLAN for all of the data.

How do I setup the *LAN* and *WAN* or OPT1 interfaces on pfSense to be VLAN trunks ?

The VLANs I have are 1, 10, 20, 30, 100 and If possible they each don't want to have an IP on the pfSense box due to space requirements, but that can be worked around if needed. Please advise this.